# How to find class name length by starting value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to find a class names by it's start `name` using the value, i am looking for different length according to the length of the name.

I am getting wrong result. any one help me to find the correct way. here is my works:

html :

```
    <div id="first">
        <span class="textHighLight userNote2">CO</span>
        <span class="textHighLight userNote2">N</span>
        <span class="textHighLight userNote2">STR</span>
        <span class="textHighLight userNote2">U</span>
        <span><span class="textHighLight userNote2">CTION</span>,</span>
    </div>

    <div id="second">
        <span class="textHighLight userNote2 userNote3">CO</span>
        <span class="textHighLight userNote2 userNote3">N</span>
        <span class="textHighLight userNote2 userNote3">STR</span>
        <span class="textHighLight userNote2 userNote3">U</span>
        <span><span class="textHighLight userNote2 userNote3">CTION</span>,</span>
    </div>
```

```js
var getLength = function (element) {
    var classLength = element.find('.textHighLight').filter(function(index){
        return this.className.split(' ').reduce(function(cNum, cName){
            return cName.substring(0, 8) === 'userNote' ? cNum + 1 : cNum;
        }, 0);
    }).length;

    return classLength;
}

var first = getLength($('#first'));
console.log(first) //returns 5 this is correct.

var second = getLength($('#second'));
console.log(second ) //returns 5 instead 10 (i am looking for 10!)
```

I understand that, I am not properly filtering the way it should be. any one help me please?

[Here is the Live](http://jsfiddle.net/L9v2r9g7/7/)

Comment: what am I missing? Why should the second one log `10`? What's your method trying to do?

Comment: I require to know, each of the elements class names length by it's start value, which i posted in title and even with my example, can't you understand the idea from my comment?

Comment: Based on my comment, obviously no. Based on its 3 upvotes, Id say im not alone!

Comment: So the first example has 5 elements starting `userNote` whereas the second has 10 - that's what you're counting?

Comment: yes, I may not explained well, but it is easy to understand. simply the first function required to console 5 (since the `userNote` instance are 5) and the next function instance is 10 (`userNote` has 10 instance in class name)

Comment: You didnt explain it very well. Consider it a skill of answering obscure SO questions for too many years that allowed me to decypher that.

Comment: yes understand, we are not born and bought in UK or US. you kind of people once understand we always requires the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not what `filter` is used for.  `filter` will filter the set of matched elements down to an equal or lesser set.  You will never get 10 if you are filtering a set of 5 elements.

You should instead just use `each` to loop over the set.

http://jsfiddle.net/L9v2r9g7/11/

```
var getLength = function (element) {
    var classLength = 0;

    element.find('.textHighLight').each(function(index){
        classLength += this.className.split(' ').reduce(function(cNum, cName){
            return cName.substring(0, 8) === 'userNote' ? cNum + 1 : cNum;
        }, 0);
    });

    return classLength;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This answer uses [`jQuery.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) to turn the array of elements into an array of numbers representing how many  classes on each element start with `userNote`. It then uses [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to simply sum those numbers up.

```js
var getLength = function (element) {
    var classLength = element.find('.textHighLight').map(function(i,e){
        return this.className.split(' ').reduce(function(cNum, cName){
            return cName.substring(0, 8) === 'userNote' ? cNum + 1 : cNum;
        }, 0);
    }).get().reduce(function(p,c){
       return p+c;  
    });

    return classLength;
}
              
console.log(getLength($('#first')))
console.log(getLength($('#second')))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first">
        <span class="textHighLight userNote2">CO</span>
        <span class="textHighLight userNote2">N</span>
        <span class="textHighLight userNote2">STR</span>
        <span class="textHighLight userNote2">U</span>
        <span><span class="textHighLight userNote2">CTION</span>,</span>
    </div>

    <div id="second">
        <span class="textHighLight userNote2 userNote3">CO</span>
        <span class="textHighLight userNote2 userNote3">N</span>
        <span class="textHighLight userNote2 userNote3">STR</span>
        <span class="textHighLight userNote2 userNote3">U</span>
        <span><span class="textHighLight userNote2 userNote3">CTION</span>,</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: In this case I imagine performance isn't really much of an issue, but I do just want to point out that you're essentially looping the elements twice, once with `map` and then again with `reduce` when it could be a single loop to handle both calculating the numbers and taking the sum.

Answer (score 2):

```
var getLength = function (element) {
    var c = 0;
    element.find('.textHighLight').each(function(i, e){
        var elem_classes = $(e).attr('class').split(' ');
        for (var i = 0; i < elem_classes.length; i++) {
            if (elem_classes[i].indexOf('userNote') > -1) {
                c++;
            }
        }
    });
    return c;
};

alert(getLength($('#second')));
```

Comment: While some explanation of the answer might be helpful, I'm unsure why this answer was downvoted.  I believe it to be a perfectly valid implementation.  +1  http://jsfiddle.net/L9v2r9g7/13/

Answer (score 0):

Other solution [fiddlejs](http://jsfiddle.net/L9v2r9g7/14/)

```
var getLength = function (element) {
    return element.find("[class]").map(function() {
        return this.className;
    }).get().join().match(/userNote/g).length;
}
var second = getLength($('#second'));
alert(second)
```